# How to use Devel module to see what creates an URL?

Tags: uri, debugging

I want to know what creates an URL of a site for example a view,panel etc.
Which command should I write on the Devel module on "Execute php" ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you are meaning by 'create url', but any url in Drupal is registered through [hook_menu()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_menu). Don't let the name confuse you - this is a seperate concept to lists of urls (like the navigation menu). The menu system keeps a cache of url to callback function mappings, which you can inspect to see which function each url points to.

To view the menu cache, you can run this code:

```
dpm(menu_router_build());
```

You can then look through the array to see the details for each url.